# Cross browser border-radius

Tags: css, cross-browser, border

When using border-radius:5px for example, how many cross browser versions are reasonable to get in the habit of using on every project?

I have been just using:

```
border-radius:5px;
-moz-border-radius:5px;
-webkit-border-radius:5px;
```

Is this going to work on all modern browsers or is there anything else that I should be doing?

Comment: Unless you have to support very very very old versions of Chrome and Firefox you won't be needing anything other than the standard syntax. [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius).

Comment: This is very much a matter of opinion. It depends on the level of browser support for the feature (you said `border-radius` was just an example), what the effects are if that particular bit of styling isn't rendered, the market share of different browsers among your audience, and how much you care.

Comment: border-radius:5px was an example of using border-radius. The question is for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of border-radius, you can simply leave it as

```
border-radius: 5px;
```

Unless you're looking to achieve support for *really* old browsers [see here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-radius)

[image]

---

For other situations/css properties, however, It would be important to include the `-ms-, -moz-, -webkit-` and unprefixed versions. By using this same website, you will find out which browsers need which prefix for each of the css properties.

Answer (score -3):

```
border-radius: 12px; /* Android 2.1+, Chrome, Firefox 4+, IE 9+, iOS 4+, Opera 10.50+, Safari 5+ */
```